# Python pandas add absolute one to positive/negative numbers in a series

Tags: python, pandas, math, absolute

I've got a series of positive and negative numbers and want to increase the absolute value of every number by one, while still keeping them positive/negative.
0.2 -> 1.2
-0.3 -> -1.3
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `sign` from `numpy`

```
s=pd.Series([0.2,-0.3])
(s.abs()+1)*np.sign(s)
0    1.2
1   -1.3
dtype: float64
```

Or `np.select`

```
np.select([s>0,s<0],[s+1,s-1],default=1)
array([ 1.2, -1.3])
```

Also we can do `np.where`

```
np.where(s>=0,s+1,s-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `np.where`:

```
s += np.where(s>=0, 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

@YOBEN_S' answer sufficiently covers it within the `pandas/numpy` space - if you are working within lists, and outside Pandas/Numpy, the below code may suffice, as it uses the [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module within python :

```
from math import fabs, copysign

[(fabs(ent)+1)*copysign(1,ent) for ent in l]

[1.2, -1.3]
```